# Is it possible to convert a BoxCollider2D to PolygonCollider2D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is it possible to convert a BoxCollider2D to PolygonCollider2D in c#?
If so, how?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by convert but you can remove the BoxCollider2D component and add a PolygonCollider2D component whenever you want via script.

Comment: You have to show what you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new PolygonCollider2D and set the properties 'pathCount' and 'points' with values from your BoxCollider2D. Then, detach the BoxCollider2D and attach the PolygonCollider2D in the gameObject.

If you need a reference that works for both types of collider, you can declare it as Collider2D or any other parent class.